# PowerShell and TFS | Getting a list of change sets from TFS with PowerShell ISE using a local path vs using a server path

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-remoting

We are trying to get a list of changesets in TFS for a specific branch using Powershell.

Tools: PowerShell ISE, TFS Server 2012, Windows 2008 R2 server SP1

For our old windows accounts on the server - a server path and local path code options, both work.

For users with new windows accounts - the local path doesn't work, but server path works.

Are we missing permissions somewhere? what kind?

```
# Enforce coding rules
Set-StrictMode -version 2.0

# Loads Windows PowerShell snap-in if not already loaded
if (
   (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell 
       -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null 
)
  {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }

$dateRange = "D" + "2020-02-13T15:02:49" + "~D" + "2020-02-20T13:37:47" 

Write-Host "---OPTION 1 (works) using a server path ---"

$TfsServer = "http://**tfs01:8080/tfs/*****"
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver $TfsServer 
$results = Get-TfsItemHistory $/SolutionName/Main -Server $tfs 
         -Recurse 
         -Version $dateRange 
         | Sort CreationDate 
         | Select ChangeSetId,OwnerDisplayName,Comment,CreationDate 
         | Select-Object ChangeSetId,CreationDate,OwnerDisplayName,Comment

foreach ($line in $results)
{
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($line))        
        {
           Write-Host $line
        }
 }


Write-Host "---OPTION 2 (doesn't work) using a local path ---"

$locationToSearch = "D:\TFS01\LP\SolutionName\Main\Project"
$results = Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch 
         -Recurse 
         -Version $dateRange 
         | Sort CreationDate 
         | Select ChangeSetId,OwnerDisplayName,Comment,CreationDate 
         | Select-Object ChangeSetId,CreationDate,OwnerDisplayName,Comment

foreach ($line in $results)
{
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($line))        
        {
           Write-Host $line
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expected using server path to get changesets.